# Gravity Forms get high number from some number fields and retur label and value of higher number

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have 8 number fields in one form, I want to know how can i get the Label and value of highest number of this 8 fields. 
I'm trying with javascript but no exit.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it would be good and a help to others if you could post the data you are trying to get the highest value from.

Comment: Hello, I have 8 number fields, Option1: 44 , Option2: 92, Option3: 35, Option4: 77, Option5:12, Option6: 33, Option7: 55,Option8: 85, I'm trying to get the higher value of this 8 fields an the label of the higher value. in this case will be label=>Option2 and value=>92